# Tabris: Is it planned to support CTabFolder?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rap

Tabris-Experts,

currently I want to use CTabFolder to have the ability to close CTabItems. Is it correct that CTabFolder is not supported in Tabris until now?

Using following code ...

```
public class TabFolderExample extends Shell {

public TabFolderExample(Display display) {
    super(display, SWT.NO_TRIM);
    createContents();
}

private void createContents() {
    setMaximized(true);
    setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
    createTabFolder();
    createCTabFolder();
}

private void createTabFolder() {
    final TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(this, SWT.NONE);

    final TabItem tab0 = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tab0.setText("Tab0");
    Text text0 = new Text(tabFolder, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.LEAD | SWT.BORDER);
    text0.setText("Content Tab0");
    tab0.setControl(text0);

    final TabItem tab1 = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tab1.setText("Tab1");
    Text text1 = new Text(tabFolder, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.LEAD | SWT.BORDER);
    text1.setText("Content Tab1");
    tab1.setControl(text1);
}

private void createCTabFolder() {
    final CTabFolder tabFolder = new CTabFolder(this, SWT.NONE);

    final CTabItem tab0 = new CTabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tab0.setText("Tab0");
    Text text0 = new Text(tabFolder, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.LEAD | SWT.BORDER);
    text0.setText("Content Tab0");
    tab0.setControl(text0);

    final CTabItem tab1 = new CTabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tab1.setText("Tab1");
    Text text1 = new Text(tabFolder, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.LEAD | SWT.BORDER);
    text1.setText("Content Tab1");
    tab1.setControl(text1);
}

@Override
protected void checkSubclass() {
    // Disable the check that prevents subclassing of SWT components
}
```

}

I get [this result on the iPad](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/962415/TabFolder%20and%20CTabFolder.PNG). The CTabFolder in the bottom is empty.

What do you suggest to work around this at the moment? I was thinking about StackLayout and Labels?

Best regards.

Comment: I have seen here [link](http://developer.eclipsesource.com/tabris/docs/client/supported-api/) that CTabFolder and CTabItem are supported on iOS. Is there a mistake in the coding above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Tabris client for iOS, CTabFolder and TabFolder are (currently) the same.
The "extended functionalities" of CTabFolder are not really applicable to the iOS default Tab/TabFolder UI. So to close a Tab you might want to rethink your user workflow for now.

We will have a look at the CTabFolder again, and see if we might implement it like Tabs are implemented on Safari for iPad. But that will definitely be farther along the roadmap.

Comment: We will remove CTabFolder from Tabris for now, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Hi. Your idea to implement CTabFolder similar to Safari is great.